# Change input param when use ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to change ng-Disabled value for one separate input which i show by ng-repeat directive.

I have:

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in langs">
    <label> <input 
             type="radio" 
             name="language"
             ng-disabled="isDisabled"
             ng-model="langs.name"
             ng-value="$index"
             ng-change="getIndex($index)"
             />
     <span> {{lang.name}} </span> 
     </label>    
</li>
```

How to do something like that:

```
$scope.langs[0].ngDisabled = true;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could allow a property 'isDisabled' to be added to your model:

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in langs">
    <label> <input 
         type="radio" 
         name="language"
         ng-disabled="lang.isDisabled"
         ng-model="lang.name"
         ng-value="$index"
         ng-change="getIndex($index)"
         />
     <span> {{lang.name}} </span> 
     </label>    
</li>
```

Then you can do:

```
  $scope.langs[0].isDisabled = true;
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to mutate your model, you could do the following instead:

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.isDisabled = {};
   $scope.langs = [
      { name: 'French' },
      { name: 'English' },
      { name: 'German' },
      { name: 'Chinese' },
      { name: 'Dutch' }
   ];


});
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='Ctrl as ctrl'> 
      <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="lang in langs">
              <label> 
                <input 
                  type="radio" 
                  name="language"
                  ng-disabled="isDisabled[lang.name]"
                  ng-model="ctrl.selectedLanguage"
                  ng-value="lang.name"
                  />
                <span> {{lang.name}} </span> 
             </label>    
          </li>          
      </ul>
     <br />
     {{ ctrl.selectedLanguage }} <br />
     {{ isDisabled }}
 </body>
```

Then you can do:

```
   $scope.isDisabled[$scope.langs[0].name] = true;
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1O4jxbdZZre9kmOuLZoC?p=preview)

Comment: Can you explain the second solution? Because i tried to do that, but it didn't work. And if i use the first variant - how to set "disabled=true" to all items in ng-repeat?

Comment: I put a demo for the second solution. Let me know if you still have questions. If you use the first solution, then loop over each lang in the controller, and set isDisabled = true